# Batch script that terminate running process and restart after certain time

Tags: python, batch-file

I am trying to create a batch script that will run for some period of time and then would terminate it and rerun the script from scratch.

This is what I have so far. When I run it, I would get

, - Invalid alias verb.

ERROR:
Description = Invalid query

```
@echo off

set pyproc="python C:\Users\David\test.py"
:: Python command with full path to script and other arguments here. Place in quotes. 
set pywait=10
:: number of seconds between kill/spawn cycle.
:begin
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('wmic /output:stdout process call create %pyproc% ^| findstr /i ProcessId') do (
set pypid="%%a"
)
set pypid=%pypid:~13,-2%
timeout /T %pywait% /NOBREAK 1>nul
wmic /output:stdout process where ProcessId=%pypid% call terminate 1>nul
goto :begin
```

So then I try running it using this code. This script works but it doesn't seem to restart. It just keep on running. When I try to run it as admin, it says test.py command not found

```
@echo off
test.py
:: Python command with full path to script and other arguments here. Place in quotes.
set pywait=%1
IF NOT EXIST pywait ( set pywait=5 )
:: number of seconds between kill/spawn cycle. Uses first argument passed to batch file in command executed, otherwise defaults to 5.
:begin
::for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('wmic /output:stdout process call create '%pyproc:"=%' ^| findstr /i ProcessId') do (
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('wmic /output:stdout process call create '%pyproc:"=%' ^| findstr /i ProcessId') do (
set pypid=%%a
)
set pypid=%pypid:~,-1%
:: stripping the semi colon
ping -n %pywait% 127.0.0.1 2>nul 1>&2
:: ping hack for getting a wait. 
wmic /output:stdout process where ProcessId=%pypid% call terminate 1>nul
:: terminates the process with the pid grabbed in the above for loop; does not break out of the script if the command is unsuccessful.
:: you can also place a redirect to a file using " 1>> C:\path\to\log\logfilename.txt " instead so you have a record of terminations. Don't let it fill up the drive though! lol
cls
:: keeps the cursor from moving everywhere in console and being distracting. If you're having issues, comment this part out. 
    goto :begin
```

Comment: [Debugging your batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_debugging.php)

Comment: you set 3 times `pypid` in your loop? why? And can't you use `taskkill /F /PID %pypid%` which is simpler? Can you print out `%pypid%` value?